# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1273: 1274

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have received this error.
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1273: 1274

This is my code

```
 //DECODING DRIVER POLYLINES START
  void driverDPo() {
    loadDriverPoly().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) => {
          snapshot.documents.forEach((f) {
            String polyDecodedStringDriver;
            polyDecodedStringDriver = f.data['decodedRouteString,'].toString();
            driverUid = f.data['uid'];
            print("polyDecodedStringDriver : " + polyDecodedStringDriver);
            print("Driver Uid : " + f.data['uid']); //asigning
            try {           
              result2 = polylinePointsDr
                  .decodePolyline(f.data['decodedRouteString,']);

              result2.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
                // driverPolylineCordinates
                //     .add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
                print("DRIVER LATLONG : " +
                    LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude).toString());
                // driverLatLng =
                //     LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude); //asigning
              });
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
          })
        });
  }
  //DECODING DRIVER POLYLINES END
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was stored overview_polyline from google map. I want to compare it with a live location. That's when the exception came. I didn't find any solution on the internet. I have checked a google map that's when I saw the root I was stored before is closed. I think that's the reason for the exception.